# Can “quick cook” brown rice be cooked in an Instant Pot?

Tags: rice, cooking-time, boiling, pressure-cooker, instant-pot

I have a package of “quick cook brown rice, and I am hoping I can cook it with my 2 quart Instant Pot. Will this work? How long should I cook it, what pressure level should I use, and what release should I use?

I’ve been able to find plenty of good information on cooking rice that is just normal raw rice or soaked, but not on “quick cook” rice.

Here is the package in question:
[image: Package front]
[image: Package back]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instant or Quick Cook rice (whether white or brown) is partially precooked, meaning part of the cooking time is already completed to cut down on the wait time for the end user. So it can be cooked more or less the same way you would regular rice in an Instant Pot... just for less time.

There's [a blog post](https://www.paintthekitchenred.com/instant-pot-parboiled-rice/) that goes into a great deal of detail about parboiled rice in an Instant Pot, but the instructions boil down to:

> Parboiled White Rice: pressure cook on High Pressure for 6 minutes.
> Parboiled Brown Rice: Pressure cook on High Pressure for 8 minutes.
> Once pressure cooking is complete, do a natural pressure release (NPR) or a 15-minute natural release if you're short on time.

Well-known brand [Minute Rice](https://minuterice.com/faqs/cooking/) has a shorter time recommendation:

> Brown Rice: Use equal amounts of rice and liquid. Stir. Use the “manual” setting with High Pressure. Set timer for 5 minutes. When cooking time has elapsed, use the “Quick Release” to vent all the steam. Remove lid and fluff rice. Serve.

It looks like in the case of Minute Brown Rice, the [stovetop cook time is 10 minutes](https://minuterice.com/products/brown-rice-instant/), so **an Instant Pot on High Pressure would cut the cook time in half**. Since your rice's instructions call for 15 minutes, an 8 minute cook time would be more appropriate.

Comment: How long does it take to get to pressure ? 8 minutes when the pressure is set ? or total time ?

Comment: Total time is going to include pressure buildup and release, so will be greater than 8 minutes -- but the Instant Pot should handle all of that itself, the user would set it for 8 minutes and let it do its thing.

Comment: but does it take less total time compared to the traditional stove top cooking (quick cook rice) ?

Comment: Is the method used to pre-cook the rice parboiling? Also, “the instructions *boil* down”—nice.

Comment: @Max It might depend on pressure level, but I think it takes about 10 minutes for the Instant Pot to get up to pressure and begin the cooking timer. So no, by these directions the rice will take longer in the Instant Pot than on the stovetop, but it might be easier and more convenient sometimes to use the Instant Pot. I live in a residence hall, so if I just need rice it’s much simpler to put in the Instant Pot than go to the kitchen, take out a pan, and babysit the burner.

Comment: @ElizaWilson Yep, the parboiling is what's done by the company before packaging it for you to finish cooking at home.

Answer (score 1):

I used this exact brand and type of rice. 10 minutes in the instant pot at high pressure with a quick release was perfect!